# How to update LocalEntry in WSO2 ESB configuration xml file

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

So if it dynamic endpoint we can update it as this. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+10%3A+Introduction+to+Dynamic+Endpoints+with+the+Registry
Problem is Can I update LocalEntry as this way .But it didn't work for me. Any help would be helpful.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse http://synapse.apache.org   /ns/2010/04/configuration/synapse_config.xsd">
<registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.ESBRegistry">
    <parameter name="root">file:./repository/samples/resources/</parameter>
    <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
</registry>

<localEntry key="local-enrty-ep-key"
            src="file:repository/samples/resources/endpoint/dynamic_endpt_1.xml"/>


<sequence name="main">
    <in>

        <send>
            <endpoint key="local-enrty-ep-key"/>
        </send>
    </in>
    <out>
        <send/>
    </out>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the answer for this :)

```
  <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.ESBRegistry">
```

should be change into

```
 <registry provider="org.apache.synapse.registry.url.SimpleURLRegistry">
```